# Wörter mit unbewussten regionalen Bedeutungsverschiedenheiten

Tags: meaning, difference, regional

Gibt es im Deutschen gewöhnliche Wörter, die Missverständnisse verursachen, weil der Empfänger eine andere Bedeutung als die gemeinte als selbstverständlich annimmt, und zwar unbewusst? Ich denke an Wörter, die im allgemeinen Gebrauch sind und die vielleicht zwischen Regionen anders verwendet worden sind. Ich denke nicht an Wörter, die man in Wörterbüchern nachschlagen kann, dass sie regionale Bedeutungsverschiedenheiten aufweisen, so wie etwa Schrank/Kasten oder Stuhl/Sessel, sondern an Wörter, die so gewöhnlich sind, dass man die Bedeutungen so selbstverständlich annimmt, dass man gar nicht darüber reflektiert?

Vielleicht drücke ich mich unklar aus, und werde es dafür mit einem Beispiel aus meiner Muttersprache, Schwedisch, illustrieren: Es gibt ein Adverbial ( „lär“ in Präsens), dessen Bedeutung für die meisten ein Modulieren des Verbs in Richtung „angeblich sein“ gibt. Meine Frau kommt aus einem Gebiet, wo man das Wort ausschließlich als „muss“ verwendet und wo man die gewöhnliche Bedeutung gar nicht kennt. Es hat für uns sehr lange gedauert, ehe wir uns über die Verschiedenheiten klar waren. Die Gummistiefel vom Kind sollten drauf, meinte sie, ich hab’s aber als „jemand meint, dass sie schon drauf sind“ verstanden. Nach dieser Episode war es uns klar, dass wir das Wort anders verwenden. Im Fernsehen, wenn Leute „auf der Straße“ interviewt werden, höre ich dies oft, was zu Verwirrung führt. Wenn ich Leute darüber frage, meinen fast alle, dass das Wort nur die eine oder die andere Bedeutung habe, eine zweite Bedeutung gäbe es nicht.

Also kennt jemand solche „gefährlichen Wörter“ im Deutschen?

Comment: Ich war erschüttert über Pfannkuchen in Berlin.

Comment: Wenn es unbewusst ist, dann weiß man es nicht. Pfannkuchen, die nicht in der Pfanne, sondern der Friteuse gemacht werden, und andernorts Berliner heißen: Manche Leute wissen von der unterschiedlichen Bedeutung, manche nicht. Wörter, deren Mehrdeutigkeit selbst Wörterbuchmachern unbekannt ist, wird es kaum geben und wir werden nicht darüber berichten können, weil es soll ja unbewusst sein. :)

Comment: Das mit unbewußt mußt du mich "richtig mißverstehen". Bei einem frühern oder späteren Zeitpunkt muss die Sache ja bewußt sein, sonst könnten wir uns daruber nicht reflektieren. In meinem Beispiel war die Bewußtheit sehr spät gekommen, trotz meines Sprachinterresse. Die abweichende Verwendungsweise ist in keinem Wörterbuch nachzuschlagen

Comment: Ist Dein Beispiel aus dem Schwedischen wirklich in keinem Wörterbuch nachzuschlagen? Selbst wenn nicht, dann finde ich, dass es eher etwas über die Qualität schwedischer Wörterbücher als über das Beispiel selbst aussagt.

Comment: Ich habe die Bedeutung in keinen gängigen Wörterbüchern gefunden. Im  Riesenwerk "SAOB" https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svenska_Akademiens_ordbok das nach mehr als 200 Jahren noch nicht fertig ist, gibt man aber auch diese Bedeutung an

Comment: Ich finde "unbewusst" im Titel problematisch. Jedem, der hier antwortet, sind die Unterschiede bewusst.

Comment: Lumpen: Die Bedeutung "Zerschlissene Kleidung" scheint die verbreitetere zu sein. In meiner Region (Pfalz) heißt "Lumpen" allerdings "(Putz-)Lappen". Dementsprechend habe ich mir im St.-Martin-Lied den Bettler, der Lumpen trägt, immer in Putzlappen gekleidet vorgestellt.

Comment: Duden, 9.: (süddeutsch, österreichisch, schweizerisch) Schrank. Btw.: Du musst Adressaten Deiner Kommentare mit @sowieso markieren, damit diese über deinen Kommentar informiert werden, außer den Hauptantworter/Frager - unsicher bin ich, ob man drauf verzichten kann, wenn es nur einen Kommentar bisher gab.

Comment: @Ludi Zu der Frage "bewusst/unbewusst": Es geht ja gerade darum, dass Leute hier antworten sollen, die sich solcher Unterschiede (aus welchen Gründen auch immer) bewusst sind, um Leute, die sich derer nicht bewusst sind, einen Hinweis zu geben. Sicherlich werden die Leute, die hier antworten, einmal über die andere Bedeutung gestolpert sein und sich daher der Unterschiede bewusst sein. Es gibt aber auch hier Beispiele, die ich nicht kannte (z.B. Fuß). Unbewusst wäre ich also auch in diese Falle getappt.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Richtig. Andererseits mutmaße ich ungern darüber, was anderen Sprechern bewusst ist. Ich habe schon beobachtet, dass der Unterschied zwischen Stuhl und Sessel vielen Österreichern "nicht bewusst" ist, aber ich sehe die Gefahr, dass diese Formulierung als offensiv gesehen wird. Jedenfalls gefällt mir Ihre Frage!

Comment: @Ludi Ist gar nicht meine Frage :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich kenne einige Unterschiede zwischen deutschem und österreichischem Deutsch:

### Kasten

In Deutschland: Ein quaderförmiger, oben offener Behälter mit Kantenlängen zwischen ca 30 und 60 cm, in dem man Getränkeflaschen oder auch Obst aufbewahrt und transportiert. In Österreich heißt dieser Gegenstand »Kiste« (Bierkiste, Obstkiste).

In Österreich: Ein quaderförmiger, vorne mit einer Tür versehener ortsfester Behälter, etwa 2 Meter hoch, 60 cm tief und 1 bis 2 Meter breit, in dem man Kleidung aufbewahrt (Kleiderkasten). In Deutschland heißt dieser Gegenstand »Schrank«. »Schrank« ist auch in Österreich aktiv in Gebrauch.

### Sessel

In Deutschland ein gepolstertes Sitzmöbel für eine Person mit weicher Rückenlehne, weicher Sitzfläche und gepolsterten Seitenteilen auf denen man die Arme ablegen kann. Also ein Einpersonen-Sofa. In Österreich heißt dieser Gegenstand »Fauteuil«.

In Österreich ist ein Sessel ein Sitzmöbel für eine Person mit Rückenlehne. Ob gepolstert oder nicht macht keinen Unterschied. Insbesondere werden auch alle Sitzmöbel, die man in Deutschland als »Stuhl« bezeichnen würde, in Östereich ebenfalls »Sessel« genannt.

### Brötchen

In Deutschland ein kleiner Brotlaib aus Weißbrot, der so klein ist, dass man davon beim Frühstück häufig zwei oder sogar mehr Stück verzehrt. In Österreich heißt diese Backware »Semmel«.

In Österreich ist ein Brötchen eine Scheibe Weißbrot (häufig schräg geschnittenes Baguette, kann aber neuerdings auch Vollkornbrot oder sogar Schwarzbrot sein), das mit exquisiter Feinkost (Kaviar, Schinken, Käse, kleinen Paradeisern, kleinen Salatblättern, Mayonnaise usw.) belegt ist. Nicht zu verwechseln mit einem Wurstbrot (beim Wurstbrot sind die Zutaten weniger edel und werden auch nicht so sorgsam aufs Brot gelegt)! Wie diese Speise in Deutschland bezeichnet wird, weiß ich leider nicht. Siehe: https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/g4h_jRJfNO5qCsDxLjad8g/ls.jpg

### Hörnchen

In Deutschland ist das Hörnchen eine Backware, vergleichbar mit dem (deutschen) Brötchen), jedoch in der Form eines Sichelmondes, und aus einem etwas anderem Teig gefertigt. In Österreich heißen diese Backwaren »Kipferl«.

In Österreich ist das Hörnchen eine spezielle Nudelform. Die Hörnchen sind hohl wie die Maccheroni, aber gekrümmt wie Kipferl. Siehe http://fddb.info/static/db/400/410/4QF6MJ37SBKPKG8V865VODVJ_999x999.jpg

### geil

Dieses Adjektiv hat in Deutschland zwei verschiedene, aber ähnliche Bedeutungen. »Du siehst geil aus« bedeutet: »Ich finde dein Aussehen attraktiv«, wobei damit durchaus auch eine sexuelle Bedeutung mitschwingt, im Sinn von »Dein Aussehen ist geeignet mich sexuell zu erregen«. Die zweite Anwendung ist »Ich bin geil« und bedeutet »Ich bin sexuell erregt.« Diese Bedeutungen sind auch in Österreich in Verwendung.

In Österreich kann »geil« aber auch bedeuten, dass eine Süßspeise, etwa eine Torte, besonders fett und süß zugleich ist. Insbesondere wird eine Cremefüllung mit hohem Zucker- und Buttergehalt oftmals als *geil* bezeichnet. Ganz ohne irgendwelchen sexuellen Anklänge. (Die Gail, die man zwar mit »ai« schreibt, aber gleich ausspricht, ist ein Fluss, der dem Gailtal in Kärnten den Namen gibt)

### mir geht einer ab

Neben vielen anderen, auch in Österreich gebräuchlichen Bedeutungen des Wortes *abgehen*, bedeutet die Phrase »mir geht einer ab« in Deutschland »ich habe einen Orgasmus« oder auch »ich ejakuliere«. Bei passendem Kontext wird das auch in Österreich verstanden.

In Österreich ist diese Phrase aber in einem anderen Kontext viel gebräuchlicher. Sie bedeutet nämlich »mir fehlt jemand«. Beispiel: Am Ende eines Schulausfluges, unmittelbar bevor der Bus abfahren soll, zählen der Lehrer die Schüler im Bus durch. Ein Schüler fehlt. Als der Lehrer das bemerkt, ruft er laut durch den Bus »Wir können noch nicht fahren, mir geht einer ab«.

### Hand und Fuß

In Deutschland endet die Hand beim Handgelenk und der Fuß beim Sprunggelenk.

In Österreich kann die Hand schon mal bis zur Schulter und der Fuß bis zur Hüfte reichen. Wer vom Schiurlaub mit einer Fraktur des Schienbeines zurückkommt, hat sich den Fuß gebrochen. Allerdings ist der Wandel zur deutschen Denkweise, in der auch Arme und Beine vorkommen, auch in Österreich schon relativ weit fortgeschritten.

### Schwamm/Schwammerl

Ein Schwamm ist in Deutschland entweder ein Meeresbewohner aus dem Stamm der Schwämme (also ein Tier), oder das Skelett dieses Tieres, oder eine Imitation dieses Skeletts aus Kunststoff (Badeschwamm, Putzschwamm).

In Österreich sind dieselben Bedeutungen ebenfalls in Verwendung. Wenn aber die Verkleinerungsform *Schwammerl* gewählt wird, ist damit keinesfalls ein kleiner Badeschwamm gemeint, sondern der Fruchtkörper eines Großpilzes. (Eierschwammerl = Pfifferling). In Deutschland werden diese Fruchtkörper mit demselben Begriff bezeichnet wie das ganze Lebewesen: Pilz.

### Schlüpfer

In Deutschland ist damit eine Unterhose gemeint, seltener auch ein Muff.

In Österreich ist ein Schlüpfer ein Schuh, den man nicht zubinden muss (Mokassins, Espandrillos, Slipper und dergleichen). Man zieht den Schuh also an, indem man einfach hineinschlüpft.

Ich glaube, es gibt noch viel mehr Wörter, die regionale Bedeutungsunterschiede haben, aber wenn man in einer bestimmten Region lebt, bekommt man die Bedeutungen in anderen Regionen häufig gar nicht mit.

Comment: Sehr schöne Zusammenstellung. Einiges war mir neu, anderes kennt (und benutzt) man besonders in Süddeutschland/Bayern genau wie in Österreich (Semmel, Schwammerl). Mit _Schwamm_ wird im Kontext von Häusern/Wohnungen auch im Norden Schimmel(-pilz) bezeichnet (Hausschwamm). Das österreichische "Brötchen" klingt für mich nach einem [Kanapee](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanapee), wobei damit auch eine Art Sofa bezeichnet wird. Ein typisches [Teekesselchen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teekesselchen).

Comment: Kasten/Schrank war explitz ausgeschlossen. Steht auch im Duden, ebenso wie Sessel/Stuhl. Müssen wir die anderen auch nachschauen oder sind das alles gut dokumentierte Mehrdeutigkeiten? Manche Leute lesen auch Bücher oder sehen fern und bekommen so was von weiter weg mit.

Comment: "Geil" und abgehen waren mir neu!

Comment: Es gab auch etwas für Glühbirne in Österreich, aber es fällt mir nicht ein - Kerze vielleicht?

Comment: @Ludi: Glühbirnen heißen in Österreich »Glühbirnen«. Als »Kerze« bezeichnen wir in Österreich ein meist zylinderförmig geformtes Stück Wachs, durch dessen Rotationsache ein Docht verläuft, an dem die Kerze angezündet werden kann. Davon abgeleitet gibt es noch in Ottomotoren die Zündkerze. Ich denke aber, das wird in Deutschland nicht viel anders sein.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ja, diese Bedeutung haben wir auch. Ich habe es auch nur von einem Paar gehört. Ich versuche es demnächst mal zu provozieren;)

Comment: "Ich bin geil!" hat nicht immer etwas sexuelles an sich (in DE). Es kann auch einfach so etwas meinen wie "Seht mal her was für ein toller Hecht ich bin". Die Nutzung von "Ich bin geil" als "Ich bin sexuell erregt" ist etwas, das eher neumodisch ist. Es kommt da aber auch immer sehr auf den Kontext und die Tonart an.

Answer (score 4):

Mir fällt in dieser Liste noch ein:

**bockig**
In wohl den meisten Regionen (wie hier in Hessen): Störrisch, widerspenstig. In Franken (zumindest im Raum Nürnberg): sexuell erregt, geil (im Sinne sexueller Geilheit, nicht im Sinne von "toll, super").

**nach/in XYZ machen**
In vielen Gebieten bedeutet *in ... machen*, dass man dorthin pinkelt. In Hessen jedoch (und eventuell auch in anderen Regionen) kann das auch bedeuten, dass man dorthin gegangen ist (z.B. Wir haben ins Kino gemacht), wo ich als Wahlhesse jedes Mal kurz zusammenzucke...

Comment: Assoziation zu »bockig«: In weiten Teilen Österreichs wird »gamsig« (abgeleitet von der Gams/Gemse) in der Bedeutung »sexuell erregt, geil« verwendet, und in Tirol kennt man ein weiteres Wort mit dieser Bedeutung: »bärig«. In derselben Region wird »bärig« aber auch in der Bedeutung »toll, super« verwendet, gleicht damit also dem Wort »geil«. »Gamsig« wird aber nur mit der sexuellen Bedeutung verwendet.

Comment: "Geil" wird "bei uns" übrigens sowohl in der sexuellen Bedeutung als auch (von der "jüngeren Generation") in der Bedeutung "toll, super" verwendet. Im obigen Beispiel meinte "geil" die sexuelle Erregung, nicht die Bedeutung "super". Ich ergänze das in der Antwort.

Answer (score 3):

Mir sind zwei solche Wörter bekannt, die in Gegenden in denen auch schwäbischer Dialekt gesprochen wird mit einer (leicht) anderen Bedeutung verwendet werden als in anderen Gegenden.
Diese Wörter werden auch dann "unbewusst" in der schwäbischen Bedeutung verwendet, wenn der Sprecher hochdeutsch spricht:

- **Teppich** - wird normalerweise als "carpet" verwendet, im Südwesten jedoch auch als "blanket"
- **Fuß** - bezeichnet im Südwesten das *gesamte* Bein, während anderswo nur der Bereich unterhalb des Knöchels gemeint wird.

Comment: Fuß ist definitiv ein gutes Beispiel. Vor Jahren wurde meine (schwäbische) Tochter mit "Schmerzen im Fuß" ins Krankenhaus eingeliefert. Der (hochdeutsche) Arzt ließ brav den Fuß röntgen und fand nichts. Tage später stellte sich heraus, dass das Bein gebrochen war.

Comment: Fuß steht mit beiden Bedeutungen im Duden.

Comment: Ja, aber mit dem Hinweis "(süddeutsch, österreichisch)" bei der Bedeutung "Bein".

Answer (score 3):

**holen/nehmen**

Im Saarland und im westlichen Rheinland-Pfalz (also etwa zwischen
Koblenz und Saarbrücken) ist das Wort "nehmen" ungebräuchlich,
stattdessen sagt man "holen". (Das gilt auch für Zusammensetzungen,
beispielsweise *"ich habe drei Kilo abgeholt"*.)

Wenn also ein Zugezogener in der Arztpraxis gefragt wird, wann er zuletzt
seine Antibiotika geholt hat, dann sollte er nicht
*"vor einer Woche in der Dorfapotheke"* antworten, sondern
*"heute morgen nach dem Frühstück"*.

Answer (score 2):

**heben** bedeutet in der Kurpfalz (Region rund um Mannheim), Schwaben und Teilen der Schweiz das, was auf hochdeutsch „halten” heißt.

„Das musst Du gut festheben” ist außerhalb dieser Regionen unverständlich.

**viertel zwölf** bedeutet u.a. in Nordostdeutschland inklusive Berlin, in Franken und in Österreich 11.15 Uhr. In anderen Regionen könnte man den Ausdruck als „viertel vor-” oder „viertel nach zwölf” missverstehen

Comment: Das mit "heben" finde ich interessant. Diese Bedeuting ist aber in den Wörterbüchrn zu finden. In meinem Wahrig als Oberdeutsch angegeben.

Comment: Was heißt "heben" denn anderswo, wenn nicht "halten"?

Comment: Das ist im Schwäbischen genauso - Wenn man etwas hebt, *lupft* man es und wenn man es dann hält, *hebt* man es.

Comment: @Crhis Naja, hoch- oder anheben? Das hat bei einer Freundin von mir, die einen Teil des medizinischen praktischen Jahres in der Schweiz in der Chirurgie gemacht hat, ordentlich Nerven gekostet, als das Chirurg meinte "hebbe" und sie den Brustkorb versucht hat, noch weiter zu öffnen...

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: O_o und was hat es den Patienten gekostet?

Comment: @steffen Nix passiert, die haben ihr das schon rechtzeitig klar gemacht :-)

Comment: @steffen Viertel Zwölf ist übrigens in Franken/Bayern eine übliche Zeitangabe. Hier ist viertel Zwölf ebenfalls 11:15, halb Zwölf 11:30 und dreiviertel Zwölf 11:45.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Die Narkose ist halt auch dazu da, damit der Patient nicht hört, was die Ärzte und Helfer reden... „Äh, brauchen wir das noch oder kann das weg?” „Weiß auch nicht, lass uns später den Internisten fragen.”

Comment: @steffen Ja, manchmal wohl besser :-D

Comment: In Österreich: Viertel zwölf = 11:15. Viertel vor zwölf = 11:45. Viertel nach zwölf = 12:15. Viertel über zwölf = 12:15. Dreiviertel zwölf = 11:45.

Comment: *Heben* ist auch bairisch, und meine preußischen Kollegen kommen damit regelmäßig nicht klar ;)